# Command Design Pattern is implemented with some mistakes?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, command-pattern

[Here](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29) in Russian Wikipedia link there is an example of C++ implementation of Command Design Pattern. As I understand from the implementation comparing with the UML class diagram I see that:

1. class Document is the Invoker in the diagram
2. class Command is the Command in the diagram
3. class InsertCommand is the ConcreteCommand in the diagram
4. class Receiver is the Receiver in the diagram

Also, as we can see from the diagram, Invoker aggregates Command. But in our case class Document does not aggregate the Command. Is it a mistake? Or is it a variation of Command pattern? How strict the UML diagram should be followed in general for designing a concrete pattern?

Comment: You don't have to be strict at all. Patterns describe commonly recurring designs, not prescribe design.

Comment: If the document does not know (how to call) the command(s) how can the document invoke their execution? (... maybe an other class is the real invoker.)

Comment: I don't understand for example is it right that class Document is the Invoker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namings for C++ example are not so good, I understand them as following:

- `Document` is a `Receiver`, the object to apply the commands on
- `Receiver` class acts as `Invoker` in terms of provided **UML** diagram.
- `main` method is a `Client`

You could take a look at Java example, it is more clean.

Comment: When I thought about the diagram I came to the same conclusion as you. But when I thought thoroughly, I understood that if `class Receiver` is the Invoker, that what does it do in `main()` which is the Client? Look the diagram. Client should use the Receiver.

Comment: Client uses Invoker, not from UML in the Russian Wiki, but from definition of the pattern: _"... The client contains the decision making about which commands to execute at which points. To execute a command, it passes the command object to the invoker object ..."_

Comment: Not completely, but definitely it is not full.

Comment: What you mean? Do you think that, as it is in the diagram, Client should use Receiver and should not use Invoker?

Comment: Client should use Invoker to perform actions on Receiver